# Jquery/Javascript: Using booleans to determine if statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement

I'm trying to make a simple turn based "battle" game. So far I have coded the choose player section down below which lets the user select a player. The clicked div animates downwards and changes colors to blue, the remaining unclicked divs move sideways. I want the unclicked divs to be enemy options the user can use to select as the opponent.

Player Choice code:

```
function selector() {
        $("#boybutton").click(function () {
            if (found === false) {
                found = true;
                antiPick = true;
                $('#girl').animate({ right: '-=600px' });
                $("#girl").css({ backgroundColor: "grey" });
                $('#boss').animate({ right: '-=600px' });
                $("#boss").css({ backgroundColor: "grey" });
                $('#boy').animate({ bottom: '-=300px' });
                $("#boy").css({ backgroundColor: "#85C1E9" });
                var input = this;
                input.disabled = true;
            }
        })
        $("#girlbutton").click(function () {
            if (found === false) {
                found = true;
                antiPick = true;
                $('#boy').animate({ right: '-=600px' });
                $("#boy").css({ backgroundColor: "grey" });
                $('#boss').animate({ right: '-=600px' });
                $("#boss").css({ backgroundColor: "grey" });
                $('#girl').animate({ bottom: '-=300px', left: '-=160px' 
});
                $("#girl").css({ backgroundColor: "#85C1E9" });
                found = true;
                var input = this;
                input.disabled = true;
            }
        })
        $("#bossbutton").click(function () {
            if (found === false) {
                found = true;
                antiPick = true;
                $('#boy').animate({ right: '-=600px' });
                $("#boy").css({ backgroundColor: "grey" });
                $('#girl').animate({ right: '-=600px' });
                $("#boss").css({ backgroundColor: "grey" });
                $('#boss').animate({ bottom: '-=300px', left: '-=300px' });
                $("#boss").css({ backgroundColor: "#85C1E9" });
                var input = this;
                input.disabled = true;
                console.log("antipick" + antiPick);
            };
        });
    };
    return antiPick;
    console.log(antiPick);
    selector();
```

This is the code for choosing an enemy, if only coded "girl" to try first: 
Note that choosing an enemy turns the color red.

```
function enemy() {
        if (antiPick === false) {
            $("#girlbutton").click(function () {
                $('#girl').animate({ right: '-=200px', bottom: '-=200px' });
                $("#girl").css({ backgroundColor: "#F1948A" });
                var input = this;
                input.disabled = true;
            })
        }
    }
    enemy();
});
```

I'm trying to use the boolean called antiPick to separate the opponent options from the picked characters.

The problem is: when I select Girl as the picked character it uses the enemy function (turns red instead of blue) instead of the selector function. I only want the enemy function to run on characters that have not been selected by the user.

Any help is appreciated!

HTML for reference:

RPG Game

```
<body>
    <button id="boybutton">
        <div id="boy">
            <div id="boyName">Boy</div>
            <div id="boyHP">HP:
            <div id="boyHealth"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</button>
<button id="girlbutton">
    <div id="girl">
        <div id="girlName">Girl</div>

        <div id="girlHP">HP:
            <div id="girlHealth"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</button>
<button id="bossbutton">
    <div id="boss">
        <div id="bossName">Boss</div>
        <div id="bossHP">HP:
            <div id="bossHealth"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</button>
```

Comment: Cant solve the problem until we see the HTML code for it. A quick suggestion for you, for if condition check you can simply use the variable name. Ex. `$("#boybutton").click(function () { if (found === false) {}};` should be changed to `$("#boybutton").click(function () { if (!found) {}};`

Comment: Got it, I've updated the HTML

Comment: Cant get anything out of it. Where are `found` and other variables initialised? Who does that? It would be great if you can create a [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of it and then show exactly what is happening?

Comment: Actually I'll get back to this question soon, I think I may have found the solution. I'll create a JS fiddle if I get stuck once more.

Comment: `antiPick` seems to be a global variable and what you need is a property for every div so you can know which div was clicked or not clicked